# How to select the first option if the ID of the user who is viewing the component is not there? Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a select where I list sellers, the issue is that I have validated that when entering that component in the select I am automatically located, the problem is that I do not go out in that list so the select is empty instead of the first option.

Example

```
<select
  v-model="filter_user" 
  class="pull-right float-right mr-2 btn btn-light btn-lg"
>
  <!-- <option v-for="user in sales_man" :key="user.id" :value="user.id" >
    {{ user.name }} 
  </option> -->
  <option value="">All sales man</option>
  <option value="3">sales man 3</option>
  <option value="4">sales man 4</option>
  <option value="7">sales man 7</option>
</select>
```

I leave the foreach that fills me the same options but commented, but to be understood I put them option 1 to 1, the issue that I am ADMIN so my ID is 1 and every time I enter that option I want to leave me in the first option to see all executives and not 1 specific, how could I do it and not show me the blank select?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Refer: [option:selected](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp)

```
<option value="" selected>All sales man</option>
```

Comment: t is that by default in the prop I pass the user ID to automatically list all incoming requests since this component will go to a view where supervisors, salesmen and administrators enter, then I being an administrator or supervisor also have access and instead of wanting to see me because I will not have requests, I would like to check the option of all automatically.

Then the v-model tries to look for the prop ID in the select but it does not find it because I am not a salesman, so it leaves it blank.

Comment: Check if the user is in the list, if is not in the list set the v-model undefined, which should show you the default. If not add the js code